# Methods to find the correlation between one variable and a set of variables

Tags: time-series, correlation, multivariate-analysis, references, spatial

I have discrete measures (let's say $I(x,y,t)$, i.e., coordinates in space and time) on a geographical map that are sampled randomly.  I also have a constant flow of optical images in several bandwidth (let say red, green, and blue). So I have a red $R(t)$, a green $G(t)$ and a blue $B(t)$ value on each point on my map, let's say every two weeks. It is possible that the sampling rates of R, G and B are not the same so that the samples are not synchronized in time. What would be the appropriate statistical tools to find a correlation between the $I(x,y,t)$ and the set ($R(x,y,t)$, $G(x,y,t)$, $B(x,y,t)$)?

My idea would be to:

- First, asses the correlation between $I(x,y,t)$ and ($R(x,y,t)$, $G(x,y,t)$, $B(x,y,t)$)
- Then, to create a model in order to calculate $I(x,y,t)$ from ($R(x,y,t)$, $G(x,y,t)$, $B(x,y,t)$)

After searching, I came across several concepts that seem to help to achieve this goal, but maybe I am totally off-base:

- Multiple correlation
- Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient
- Covariance

Could someone give me some clues, or keywords to help me to orient my search? That is, what would be a good start to dig into that problem?

Comment: Are x & y spatial coordinates (eg, latitude & longitude) or just 2 features (eg, local temperature & rainfall)? (I take it t is time.) In other words, are you just trying to figure out if reds are more likely in a given spot, or if color is associated w/ some predictor variables?

Comment: Yes, x and y are spatial coordinates, t is time.
Sorry I don't know if I correctly understand "predictor variables". 

Indeed there are two phases:
- a first phase to estimate the correlation between the measures of the $I(x,y,t)$ and ($R(x,y,t)$, $G(x,y,t)$, $B(x,y,t)$)
- a second phase of creation of a model to compute whatever $I(x,y,t)$, given a set of  ($R(x,y,t)$, $G(x,y,t)$, $B(x,y,t)$)

Comment: This is a complex setting - no wonder that you are a bit stuck! Is $I(x,y,t)$ a count? Or what else can you tell us about $I$?

Comment: $I$ is a value (e.g. intensity), so to my opinon, not a count. Is it? It is a sample taken in a certain time and space. This sample has  correlations with $R(x,y,t)$, $G(x,y,t)$, $B(x,y,t)$, and that is what I shall determine.